combining objects in rpy2
I have the following code that takes a pandas dataframe and creates ggplot object using rpy2. It used to work just fine with rpy2 version 3.4.5
df = pandas.DataFrame({'date': datecol, 'val0': val0, 'val1': val1})
combinedplot = gg2.ggplot(df) + gg2.aes_string(x='date', y='val0')

where gg2 is rpy2 module ggplot2
type of combinedplot is rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2.GGPlot, and I can display the image of the plot using various ways.
I upgraded to rpy2 3.5.11, and this code snippet no longer works. type of combinedplot is now a rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector. I'm not sure why, but I'm guessing it has something to do with how rpy2 combines objects.
What exactly is going on here?
If my objective is to create a ggplot object so I can generate an image, how do I do it?
